# When do Svelte derived stores cause a re-render?

Tags: svelte, svelte-store

If dealing with a store shaped like this:

```
{
  "count": 0,
  "items": []
}
```

And having two derived stores (`$countStore` and `$itemsStore`) that return the respective fields, updating `items` on the main store does not cause a re-render on components that depend on just `countStore`, but updating `count` does cause a render on components that depend on just `itemsStore`, why exactly is that?

[Here's a REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c797c43b9da04f28b2ea5e3292e43f48?version=3.49.0) showing this behavior.

I would assume this happens for all non-primitive fields, but selectors in Redux for example don't have this behavior, so how does Svelte diff derived stores? Does it simply ignore non-primitive fields causing renders for every update? If so, is there a way to save on renders when dealing with objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Svelte uses a function called [`safe_not_equal`](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/4617c0d5f5af1dae09cc00ce0134e433588a62d1/src/runtime/internal/utils.ts#L39) to check whether a value potentially changed; this is not unique to derived stores. `derived` uses a `readable` store internally and the check happens on setting its value.

```js
export function safe_not_equal(a, b) {
    return a != a ? b == b : a !== b || ((a && typeof a === 'object') || typeof a === 'function');
}
```

So yes, non-primitive values are not considered the same, because they could potentially have changed internally. Svelte already optimizes updates to only cause minimal updates to the DOM, so I would not worry about this unless it really becomes an issue. For arrays you should use keyed `{#each}`-blocks to keep the DOM elements synchronized with their respective items.

Comment: That perfectly answers my question, but just to be clear, is it safe to assume that reactive statements (using $ syntax) also imply a DOM update given the same dependencies? In other words, if I write $: console.log($store.count) is that a fair way to display DOM updates in the console for DOM elements that depend on $store.count? This is related to the question as it's what I use to count renders in my example, but you say Svelte optimizes DOM updates so there could be something else going on just with DOM nodes.

Comment: Using a reactive statement is not equivalent to a DOM update happening. For the count store it would be, if the count is inserted somewhere in the HTML, but that is not how you would usually use the items. If you access the items store via `{#each}` then even though the store might be flagged as potentially changed, the DOM will not be affected until you actually change the array. Svelte tries to update the DOM only when necessary , that is why things like keyed each blocks exist; they preserve any DOM/components that already exist for a given item.